# Running git, complaints Executable requires at least macOS 10.13. Is there a workaround?

Tags: xcode, git, macos

Recently I install xcode 9.3 (from 9.1). After installing it complaints

`You have macOS 12.06.2. This application requires macOs 10.13.2 or later`

So I'm okay with that, and plan to get admin to update when they are available. But when I try to run `git`, it also complaints

`Executable requires at least macOS 10.13, but is being run on macOS 10.12.6, and so is exiting.git: error: unable to locate xcodebuild, please make sure the path to the Xcode folder is set correctly!
git: error: You can set the path to the Xcode folder using /usr/bin/xcode-select -switch`

To have my machine upgrade to the next version of macOS will be awhile. Is there a workaround that I could still run `git` without upgrading my OS?

Answer (score 0):

I just remove the `xcode` entirely from the Application, and now my `git` is working again like charm.